# How can I interpret a 'regex e' line?

Tags: c++, data-structures

My function balanceFile returns true if my braces in a file are balanced. For example:

> {()}      // balanced
>
> {(\n)} // balanced
>
> {(}       // unbalanced

I am using a switch statement provided by my CS professor shown below:

```
case 8: {
        istringstream iss("{(\n)}");
        assert(balanceFile(iss));
        string str = strCout.str();
        regex e("pair *matching *\\( *and *\\).*\\npair*matching *\\{ *and *\\}");
        assert(regex_search(str, e));}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Assertion failed: regex_search(str,e), file c:\...'
```

What is causing the assertion failure?

Answer (score 3):

The assertion failure is caused because the thing in [`assert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) is false. That's what `assert()` does. Literally, the whole point of it is to cause an assertion failure if the thing between the brackets is false.

The reason `regex_search(str, e)` is false is because the regex `e` didn't match any part of the string `str`.

Comment: ostringstream strCout;
 streambuf_switcher sso(cout, strCout); These two lines come right before the switch statement. Can you please help me understand what is strCout?

Comment: @CarlosRobinAlvarenga I believe the point of that is that anything you write to cout goes to strCout instead. Of course I don't know that for sure since streambuf_switcher is something your professor wrote. So str holds the messages you sent to cout.

Comment: It's also a really weird use of a regex. It's matching "pair matching ()" "pair matching {}" plus any amount of spaces between each word.

Comment: @Caleth I'm guessing the assignment says to output that message for each pair.